# Compile Cpp file which is using VTK library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, vtk

I want to compile `cpp` source code in which `VTK`, `Eigen`, `PETSc` and `dealII` libraries are included. source files are located in `src` directory and header files in `ìnclude` directory.

The `CMakeLists.txt`file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.3)

project(ddm_library)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wsign-compare -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeprecated-copy")

set(VTK_DIR /home/mehdi/myFolder/programming/lib/VTK-9.0.3/build)

# PkgConfig 
find_package(PkgConfig)

# PETSc
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    pkg_check_modules(PETSC PETSc)
endif()


# include PETSC
if (PETSC_FOUND)
    list(APPEND COMPILE_OPTIONS ${PETSC_CFLAGS})

    include_directories(${PETSC_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    
    set(LINK_FLAGS "${LINK_FLAGS} ${PETSC_LDFLAGS}")   
    
    list(APPEND LIBRARIES ${PETSC_LINK_LIBRARIES})   
    
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS ${PETSC_CFLAGS})   
    
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "${PETSC_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()


# include Eigen
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

# VTK library
find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
  vtkCommonColor
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkCommonDataModel
  vtkInteractionStyle
  vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingCore
  vtkRenderingFreeType
  vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingOpenGL2
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkCommonDataModel
  vtkIOXML
  QUIET
)

if (NOT VTK_FOUND)
  message("Skipping StructuredGrid: ${VTK_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE}")
  return ()
endif()

message (STATUS "VTK_VERSION: ${VTK_VERSION}")


# dealII
FIND_PACKAGE(deal.II 9.3.0 QUIET
  HINTS ${deal.II_DIR} ${DEAL_II_DIR} ../ ../../ $ENV{DEAL_II_DIR}
  )

IF(NOT ${deal.II_FOUND})
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "\n"
    "*** Could not locate a (sufficiently recent) version of deal.II. ***\n\n"
    "You may want to either pass a flag -DDEAL_II_DIR=/path/to/deal.II to cmake\n"
    "or set an environment variable \"DEAL_II_DIR\" that contains this path."
    )
ENDIF()

DEAL_II_INITIALIZE_CACHED_VARIABLES()

if (VTK_VERSION VERSION_LESS "8.90.0")
  # old system
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include ${VTK_USE_FILE} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

  file (GLOB LIB "src/*.cc")

  ADD_LIBRARY(lib ${LIB})

  vtk_module_autoinit(
    TARGETS lib
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )

  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(lib)

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE "test/main.cc")

  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME})
  
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE lib Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

else ()
  # include all components
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include ${VTK_USE_FILE} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

  file (GLOB LIB "src/*.cc")

  ADD_LIBRARY(lib ${LIB})

  vtk_module_autoinit(
    TARGETS lib
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )

    DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(lib)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE "test/main.cc")

  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME})
  
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE lib Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

  # vtk_module_autoinit is needed
  vtk_module_autoinit(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )
endif ()
```

running `cmd` like

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.7.3") 
-- Checking for module 'PETSc'
--   Found PETSc, version 3.15.0
-- VTK_VERSION: 9.0.3
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mehdi/myFolder/programming/domain_decomposition/build
```

which finds all the packages. Then running the `cmd`

```
$ make
cc1plus: warning: /home/mehdi/myFolder/programming/lib/VTK-9.0.3/build/lib/cmake/vtk-9.0/vtk-use-file-deprecated.cmake: not a directory
In file included from /home/mehdi/myFolder/programming/domain_decomposition/src/post_processing.cc:2:
/home/mehdi/myFolder/programming/domain_decomposition/include/post_processing.hpp:14:10: fatal error: vtkActor.h: No such file or directory
   14 | #include <vtkActor.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can not understand why I got such a error.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the `CMakeLists.txt`by removing `PRIVATE`from `target_link_libraries`and add `target_link_libraries`for `lib`, and the problem solved. The new `CMakeLists.txt` is look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.3)

project(ddm_library)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wsign-compare -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wdeprecated-copy")

set(VTK_DIR /home/mehdi/myFolder/programming/lib/VTK-9.0.3/build)

# PkgConfig 
find_package(PkgConfig)

# PETSc
if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    pkg_check_modules(PETSC PETSc)
endif()


# include PETSC
if (PETSC_FOUND)
    list(APPEND COMPILE_OPTIONS ${PETSC_CFLAGS})

    include_directories(${PETSC_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    
    set(LINK_FLAGS "${LINK_FLAGS} ${PETSC_LDFLAGS}")   
    
    list(APPEND LIBRARIES ${PETSC_LINK_LIBRARIES})   
    
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS ${PETSC_CFLAGS})   
    
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "${PETSC_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
endif()


# include Eigen
find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

# VTK library
find_package(VTK COMPONENTS
  vtkCommonColor
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkCommonDataModel
  vtkInteractionStyle
  vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingCore
  vtkRenderingFreeType
  vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2
  vtkRenderingOpenGL2
  vtkCommonCore
  vtkCommonDataModel
  vtkIOXML
  QUIET
)

if (NOT VTK_FOUND)
  message("Skipping StructuredGrid: ${VTK_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE}")
  return ()
endif()

message (STATUS "VTK_VERSION: ${VTK_VERSION}")


# dealII
FIND_PACKAGE(deal.II 9.3.0 QUIET
  HINTS ${deal.II_DIR} ${DEAL_II_DIR} ../ ../../ $ENV{DEAL_II_DIR}
  )

IF(NOT ${deal.II_FOUND})
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "\n"
    "*** Could not locate a (sufficiently recent) version of deal.II. ***\n\n"
    "You may want to either pass a flag -DDEAL_II_DIR=/path/to/deal.II to cmake\n"
    "or set an environment variable \"DEAL_II_DIR\" that contains this path."
    )
ENDIF()

DEAL_II_INITIALIZE_CACHED_VARIABLES()

#INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if (VTK_VERSION VERSION_LESS "8.90.0")
  # old system
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include ${VTK_USE_FILE} ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

  FILE (GLOB LIB "src/*.cc")

  ADD_LIBRARY(lib OBJECT ${LIB})

  vtk_module_autoinit(
     TARGETS lib
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )

  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
  
  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(lib)

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE "test/main.cc")

  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME})
  
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

else ()
  # include all components
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

  FILE (GLOB LIB "src/*.cc")

  ADD_LIBRARY(lib OBJECT ${LIB})

  vtk_module_autoinit(
     TARGETS lib
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )

  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(lib Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(lib)
  
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE "test/main.cc")

  DEAL_II_SETUP_TARGET(${PROJECT_NAME})
  
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib Eigen3::Eigen ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
  
  # vtk_module_autoinit is needed
  vtk_module_autoinit(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )
endif ()
```